# C++, remove duplication when calling same function

Tags: c++, class

I wrote a class named IntMatrix which contains 3 parameters:
rows (number of rows of the matrix), columns (number of columns of the matrix), data (an array of int which size is row*column -allocated using new-)

I wrote the following function:

```
mtm::IntMatrix mtm::IntMatrix::operator<(int num) const {
    IntMatrix result=*this;
    int size=dims.getRow()*dims.getCol();
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (result.data[i]<num)
        {
            result.data[i]=1;
        } 
        else
        {
            result.data[i]=0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It returns a matrix of the same size of the current one and returns 1 whenever the value is `< num` and 0 elsewhere.

But what if I want to write the same function for other operators like `<=, >=, >, ==` etc...
It seems I'm just copying my code over and over agains...
I read that we can use functors here, could someone give an example please?

Comment: C++20 had `operator<=>` for just this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about functors, lambda functions seem the obvious thing to use

```
template <class Func>
mtm::IntMatrix mtm::IntMatrix::transform(Func func) const {
    IntMatrix result = *this;
    int size = dims.getRow()*dims.getCol();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        result.data[i] = func(result.data[i]);
    return result;
}

mtm::IntMatrix mtm::IntMatrix::operator<(int num) const {
    return transform([=](int data){ return data < num : 1 : 0});
}

mtm::IntMatrix mtm::IntMatrix::operator>(int num) const {
    return transform([=](int data){ return data > num : 1 : 0});
}
```

`transform` is written so you could apply any transformation to your matrix, not just comparison with a number.

Untested code.

Comment: why functors won't help here?

Comment: @clark_smith You could do it with functors, it's just that lambda functions are a lot more consise. And in any case a lambda function is more than likely to be translated into a functor by the compiler.

Comment: @clark_smith In fact `transform` will accept either a lambda function or a functor (or anything else that is function like), so write a functor if you wish and pass it to `transform`.